# How to DRY a list of functions in ruby that are differ only by a single line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dry

I have a User model in a ROR application that has multiple methods like this

```
#getClient() returns an object that knows how to find certain info for a date
#processHeaders() is a function that processes output and updates some values in the database
#refreshToken() is function that is called when an error occurs when requesting data from the object returned by getClient()


  def transactions_on_date(date)
    if blocked?
      # do something
    else
      begin
        output = getClient().transactions(date)
        processHeaders(output)
        return output
      rescue UnauthorizedError => ex
        refresh_token()
        output = getClient().transactions(date)
        process_fitbit_rate_headers(output)
        return output
      end
    end
  end

  def events_on_date(date)
    if blocked?
      # do something
    else
      begin
        output = getClient().events(date)
        processHeaders(output)
        return output
      rescue UnauthorizedError => ex
        refresh_token()
        output = getClient().events(date)
        processHeaders(output)
        return output
      end
    end
  end
```

I have several functions in my User class that look exactly the same. The only difference among these functions is the line `output = getClient().something(date)`. Is there a way that I can make this code look cleaner so that I do not have a repetitive list of functions.

Comment: It's worth noting that Ruby style strongly recommends using names like `get_client` over `getClient` and omitting brackets when no arguments are passed. Additionally, for a simple "getter" method, omit `get` entirely. Methods `client` and `client=` are highly preferable to `get_client` and `set_client`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is usually passing in a block and doing it functional style:

```
def handle_blocking(date)
  if blocked?
   # do something
  else
    begin
      output = yield(date)
      processHeaders(output)

      output
    rescue UnauthorizedError => ex
      refresh_token
      output = yield(date)
      process_fitbit_rate_headers(output)

      output
    end
  end
end
```

Then you call it this way:

```
handle_blocking(date) do |date|
  getClient.something(date)
end
```

That allows a lot of customization. The `yield` call executes the block of code you've supplied and passes in the `date` argument to it.

The process of DRYing up your code often involves looking for patterns and boiling them down to useful methods like this. Using a functional approach can keep things clean.

Comment: I would consider specifying the `&block` in the arguments and using `if block_given?`

Comment: @max It's only necessary to specify `&block` in the arguments if you're intending to pass that through to another method. Declaring it in the arguments introduces a whole bunch of overhead, so it's bad to get in the habit of doing that for no reason. Since this is dependent on having a block, it should crash if you don't call it correctly. `block_given?` would be useful if there was a case where it'd have a default behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-send): `getClient().send(:method_name, date)`.

BTW, `getClient` is not a proper Ruby method name. It should be `get_client`.

Answer (score 0):

How about a combination of both answers:

```
class User

  def method_missing sym, *args
    m_name = sym.to_s
    if m_name.end_with? '_on_date'
      prop = m_name.split('_').first.to_sym
      handle_blocking(args.first) { getClient().send(prop, args.first) }
    else
      super(sym, *args)
    end
  end

  def respond_to? sym, private=false
    m_name.end_with?('_on_date') || super(sym, private)
  end

  def handle_blocking date
    # see other answer
  end

end
```

Then you can call "transaction_on_date", "events_on_date", "foo_on_date" and it would work.